# Solving a differential equation in matrix form but adding a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that if I have a system of coupled differential equations with some initial values, e.g.
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x'_1 &= 2x_1+3x_2, \\
x'_2 &= x_1-x_2.
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

I can solve that by using matrices. Let $$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},$$
$$X= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix},$$
and
$$X'= \begin{pmatrix} x'_1 \\ x'_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the system can be written as
$$X'=AX.$$

My question is: if I change the equations by adding some constants, e.g.
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x'_1 &= 2x_1+3x_2 + 5, \\
x'_2 &= x_1-x_2 - 4.,
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
how would I do that in terms of matrices?

Comment: This is not a physics question and would be better posted on Mathematics stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you will have
$$X'=AX+B$$
where
$$B= \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a common form in control theory:

$$\dot{x} = A x + B u$$

where $x$ and $u$ are *state and input vectors*, while $A$ and $B$ are *system matrices* of appropriate dimension.

You can solve this in Laplace domain:

$$sX(s) - x(0) = A X(s) + B U(s)$$

from which it follows:

$$\boxed{X(s) = (sI-A)^{-1} B U(s) + (sI-A)^{-1} x(0)}$$

---

Matrices and vectors for your example are:

$$
x = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{array}
\right] ,
\quad
A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 3 \\ 1 & -1
\end{array}
\right],
\quad
B = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
5 \\ -4
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and $u(t) = \mu(t)$ (step-wise function) with transformation $U(s) = \frac{1}{s}$.